# Add, move, resize, replace or delete qgraphicslineitem or another graphics object

Tags: c++, qt

Colleagues warned me that I was wrong to ask. That's why I completely redrafted my pervious question.

a) where best to create a new line

b) how to reliably select a specific line between 20 others

c) how best to move starting point of a line

d) how best to move end point of a line

e) how best to move line

f) how to delete a line

Everything is described in the documentation and examples, but each example chooses a different place for the actions. Someone uses the view, some scene and the other does most of the things in line. Someone uses bouding rect, another not, someone uses editing mode in view another not etc...

myscene.cpp

```
#include "myscene.h"
#include "myview.h"
#include "mymovingpoint.h"
#include <qgraphicsitem.h>
#include <qgraphicsview.h>
#include <qobject.h>
#include <qgraphicsview.h>
#include <qpoint.h>
#include <qmath.h>

/*
 *
 *
 */
myScene::myScene(QObject *parent)
    : QGraphicsScene(parent)
{
    myMode = myMode::InsertItem;
}
/*
 *
 *
 */
void myScene::mouseDoubleClickEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *mouseEvent)
{
    # remove item added by clickevent, if doubleclicked
    if(line)
    {
        removeItem(line);
    }

    # if doubleclick and left button, select existing item
    if(mouseEvent->buttons().testFlag(Qt::LeftButton))
    {
        //QGraphicsItem *item = itemAt(mouseEvent->scenePos(), QTransform());
        # itemAt() returns only the object exactly under the mouse
        # function  getNearObject return object 3 points around
        QGraphicsItem *item = getNearObject(mouseEvent);
        if(item)
        {
            myMode = myMode::EditItem;

            myLineItem *tempLine = dynamic_cast<myLineItem*>(item);
            oldLine = line;
            line = tempLine;
            QColor myclr;
            myclr.setRgb(255,0,0,255);
            line->setPen(QPen(myclr, 2));
            line->addMovingPoints();
        }
        else
        {
            myMode = myMode::InsertItem;
        }
    }
}
/*
 *
 *
 */
#return nearest objects
QGraphicsItem* myScene::getNearObject(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *mouseEvent)
{
    int roundvalue = -3;
    int roundx;
    int roundy;

    QPointF pointf = mouseEvent->scenePos();
    QPointF pointtmp;

    roundx = roundvalue;
    roundy = roundvalue;
    while(roundy <= roundvalue*-1)
    {
        while(roundx <= roundvalue*-1)
        {
            pointtmp.setX(pointf.x()-roundx);
            pointtmp.setY(pointf.y()-roundy);
            QGraphicsItem *item = itemAt(pointtmp, QTransform());
            if(item)
            {
                return item;
            }
            roundx += 1;
        }
        roundx += roundvalue;
        roundy += 1;
    }
    return NULL;
}
/*
 *
 *
 */
void myScene::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *mouseEvent)
{
    if(mouseEvent->buttons().testFlag(Qt::LeftButton))
    {
        QGraphicsItem *item = itemAt(mouseEvent->scenePos(), QTransform());
        if(myMode == myMode::InsertItem)
        {
            if(oldLine)
            {
                myLineColor.setRgb(213, 182, 10, 255);
                oldLine->setPen(QPen(myLineColor, 2));
            }
        }

        if(myMode == myMode::EditItem)
        {
            myLineItem *tempLine = dynamic_cast<myLineItem*>(item);
            if(tempLine)
            {
                oldLine = line;
                line = tempLine;
                QColor myclr;
                myclr.setRgb(255,0,0,255);
                line->setPen(QPen(myclr, 2));
                myMovingPoint myPoint(line);
            }
        }
        else if(myMode == myMode::InsertItem)
        {
            oldLine = line;

            if(mouseEvent->modifiers() & Qt::ControlModifier)
            {
                line = new myLineItem(QLineF(toNearest5(mouseEvent->scenePos()), toNearest5(mouseEvent->scenePos())));
            }
            else
            {
                line = new myLineItem(QLineF(mouseEvent->scenePos(), mouseEvent->scenePos()));
            }

            myLineColor.setRgb(213, 182, 10, 255);
            line->setPen(QPen(myLineColor, 2));
        }
        else
        {
            QGraphicsScene::mousePressEvent(mouseEvent);
        }
    }
}
/*
 *
 *
 */
void myScene::mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *mouseEvent)
{
    if(!items().contains(line))
    {
        addItem(line);
    }

    if(mouseEvent->buttons().testFlag(Qt::LeftButton))
    {
        QLineF newLine;
        if(myMode == myMode::InsertItem)
        {
            if(mouseEvent->modifiers() & Qt::ControlModifier)
            {
                newLine = QLineF(toNearest5(line->line().p1()), toNearest5(mouseEvent->scenePos()));
            }
            else
            {
                newLine = QLineF(line->line().p1(), mouseEvent->scenePos());
            }
            myLineColor.setRgb(213, 182, 10, 255);
            line->setLine(newLine);
            update();
        }
        else if(myMode == myMode::EditItem)
        {
            QLineF newLine = QLineF(line->line().p1(), mouseEvent->scenePos());
            line->setLine(newLine);
            update();
        }
    }
    QGraphicsScene::mouseMoveEvent(mouseEvent);
}
/*
 *
 *
 */
void myScene::mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *mouseEvent)
{
    myMode = myMode::InsertItem;
    QGraphicsScene::mouseReleaseEvent(mouseEvent);
}
/*
 *
 *
 */
void myScene::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent * keyEvent)
{
    if(keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_Delete)
    {
        if(line)
        {
            removeItem(line);
        }
    }
}
/*
 *
 *
 */
QPointF myScene::toNearest5(QPointF i)
{
    int shift = 10;

    int r = i.x();
    int s = i.y();

    r = (i.x()+5.0)/10;
    s = (i.y()+5.0)/10;

    r = r*10;
    s = s*10;

    QPointF output = QPointF(r, s);
    return (output);
}
```

mysceneview.cpp

```
#include "myview.h"
#include <qmath.h>
#include <qmatrix.h>


myView::myView(QGraphicsScene *scene, QWidget *parent)
    : QGraphicsView(scene, parent)
{
}


void myView::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
    QGraphicsView::keyPressEvent(event);
}


void myView::keyReleaseEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
    QGraphicsView::keyReleaseEvent(event);
}

void myView::enterEvent(QEvent *event)
{
    viewport()->setCursor(Qt::ArrowCursor);
    QGraphicsView::enterEvent(event);
}


void myView::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
{
    if (event->modifiers() & Qt::ControlModifier)
    {
        viewport()->setCursor(Qt::ArrowCursor);
        _lastPos = QPoint(event->pos());
        //_lastPos = QPoint(event->pos().x()-event->pos().x()%5, event->pos().y()-event->pos().y()%5);
    }
    else
    {
        viewport()->setCursor(Qt::ArrowCursor);
        _lastPos = event->pos();
    }
    QGraphicsView::mousePressEvent(event);
}


void myView::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
{
    viewport()->setCursor(Qt::ArrowCursor);

    if (event->buttons().testFlag(Qt::RightButton))
    {
        QScrollBar *hBar = horizontalScrollBar();
        QScrollBar *vBar = verticalScrollBar();
        QPoint delta = event->pos() - _lastPos;
        _lastPos = event->pos();
        hBar->setValue(hBar->value() + (isRightToLeft() ? delta.x() : -delta.x()));
        vBar->setValue(vBar->value() - delta.y());
        //event->ignore();
    }
    QGraphicsView::mouseMoveEvent(event);
}


void myView::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
{
    viewport()->setCursor(Qt::ArrowCursor);
    QGraphicsView::mouseReleaseEvent(event);
}



#if QT_CONFIG(wheelevent)
void myView::wheelEvent(QWheelEvent *e)
{
        if (e->delta() > 0)
        {
            x=x+0.1;
            qreal scale = x;

            QMatrix matrix;
            matrix.scale(scale, scale);

            setMatrix(matrix);
            //zoomIn(6);
        }
        else
        {
            x=x-0.1;
            qreal scale = x;

            QMatrix matrix;
            matrix.scale(scale, scale);

            setMatrix(matrix);
            //zoomOut(6);
        }
        e->accept();
}
#endif
```

Comment: Recommend reading though your question and organizing it better. In its current state is is a disjointed read and will probably result in some confused and confusing attempted answers.

Comment: Yes, you should also show us what you have tried, and post your current state/code you have.

Comment: I will add my code here, but it is very messy, because I have experimented a lot and was looking for the right way.

Answer (score 1):

you should define in your model, what's a scene, what's a view, and what is and an item.

logically this is how it goes:
**scene**: collection of drawable objects, cannot be viewed.

**view**: a window on the scene, if the object belonging to the scene is in this window, it is shown, if it is not then it's occluded

**item**: is a draw-able object, stores the position of its vertex in object coordinate.

when you draw you draw in the view, then the object stores the points in its object space coordinate, they will be constant during zooms, moves, rotations and pans, they change only when you select the vertex and move it in the view.

so `mylineitem` is only a container for an absolute coordinate.
`scene` is a container of all the `mylineitem`, just a list of objects
`view` is your controller of the way the system draws the items of the scene.

this model allows you to export your drawable items either individually or as a scene without worrying about remaping the points to the new coordinate space of the new view.

Do all your object editing in the view, because it defines the distance between the points in its coordinate system.

expl:
view, coordinate system: Cartesian, 10x10x10 cm

your draw a line p1-p2

p1(0,0,0) origin of the object space, p2(1,1,1) and it maps in the view to p1view(3,5,4) expl and p2view(13,15,14) in view coordinate. means each unit in object space is 10cm in view space.

export this line to another view where system: 20x20x20 cm then line keeps its relative size and changes its coordinate to preserve it.